# how can i link a list element with the select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a list of elements:

```
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
```

and a dropdown:

```
<select>    
    <options value="A">A</options> 
    <options value="B">B</options>    
</select>
```

How can i link both of them together?

I want to change the value of select to the text of the `<li>` that the user clicks.  So if the user clicks `<li>A</li>`, the `<select>` value would be set to A.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. I have no idea what you want. Provide some code or a link to an example or something.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
  var elem=$(this).text();
  $("select option[value='"+elem+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#list li").click(function(){

var index = $(this).text(); 

$("#dropdown").val(index);

});
```

Here's one way, though you can change the `index` variable to suit your needs.